# Making iteration and application of a function over a column in a matrix more efficient

Tags: r, element

My data looks approximately like this (millions of rows):

```
Customers    Market    Firm    
1             NY        A
2             LA        B
1             LA        A
1             NY        A
...           ...       ...
```

Some of the entries in the "Firm" Column are equal to 'x', and I need to ignore those rows.

I need to create another matrix with Markets as the rows and Firms as the columns, with each element being the sum of "Customers" for each Market-Firm pair.

The code I'm currently using is a relatively straightforward for-loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(mydata$Customers)) { 
  if(mydata$Firm[i]!="x") {
    newmatrix[mydata$Market[i],mydata$Firm[i]] <- newmatrix[mydata$Market[i],mydata$Firm[i]] + mydata$Customers[i]
  }
}
```

It works, but it takes FOREVER. Is there a way I can speed it up? I'm new to R, but I understand that doing these kinds of operations is supposed to be more simple...

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ Market + Firm, data = mydata, sum)`

Comment: Thank you! This returns a condensed (many)x3 matrix with columns Market, Firm, Customers. Is there now an easy way to turn that into a matrix with columns for each firm and rows for each market?

Comment: `with(mydata, tapply(Customers, list(Market, Firm), sum))`